# ckeditor cdn preview feature not working

Tags: ckeditor

I have ckeditor added to my textarea box and is working perfect but just one little question

How do I get the preview feature to work, when I click on it, it opens a blank white page

below is the code that I use in my php page

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/full/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Thank you in advance

Ian